# Reverse dataframe colnames around a delimiter?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
testData <-read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
id    foo1_varA foo2_varA  t1_varB t2_varB
'01'   'A'      'D'        '1'     '4'
'02'   'B'      'E'        '2'     '5'
'03'   'C'      'F'        '3'     '6'
")
```

I want to rename columns by reversing the order of the text on each side of the '_' when it is present, resulting in column names:

```
id varA_foo1, varA_foo2, varB_t1, varB_t2
```

The number of columns varies with the source data because it is the result of a data.table CAST operation.

I can do this with a single string:

```
foo <- "AA_BB"
parts <- unlist(strsplit(foo,  split='_'))
foo2 <- paste0(parts[2], "_", parts[1])
```

But I do not know how to apply this with colnames().

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
names(df) <- gsub('(.*)_(.*)', '\\2_\\1', names(df))
```

which gives,

```
names(df)
#[1] "id"        "varA_foo1" "varA_foo2" "varB_t1"   "varB_t2"
```